# get the vid of last saved vocabulary

Tags: taxonomy-terms

How can I get the last saved vid. `taxonomy_vocabulary_save($vocabulary);` is not returning the vid.
I have used the following way.

```
$vocabulary = new stdClass();
$vocabulary->name = 'Currencies';
$vocabulary->machine_name = 'currencies';
taxonomy_vocabulary_save($vocabulary);
// get the vid of currency
$vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('currencies');
//save a variable for vid
variable_set('currencies_vid', $vocabulary->vid);
```

Is there any better method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vocabulary object that you pass to `taxonomy_vocabulary_save()` will automatically be populated with the new `vid`, so you don't need to reload the vocabulary after you've saved it.

This code will work fine:

```
$vocabulary = new stdClass();
$vocabulary->name = 'Currencies';
$vocabulary->machine_name = 'currencies';
taxonomy_vocabulary_save($vocabulary);

variable_set('currencies_vid', $vocabulary->vid);
```